# Better way than DOM with no unique identifiers?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm still messing around learning php simple DOM and ran into a puzzling scenario.  There are no unique tags to actually use to specify what I want, its all just a ton of `<a>` tags.  Except for the fact that they are grouped in between comments.

If I do a

```
foreach($html->find('comment a') as $a){
    $articles[] = array($a->href,$a->innertext);
}
```

I get a ton of stuff.  So is there a way to specify that I want all the `<a>` tags between the first and second comment, the third and fourth etc. OR is DOM not the best thing to use in a situation like there where its just a mess of html.

Snippet:

```
<! FIRST COLUMN STARTS HERE>
<center><table CELLPADDING="3" WIDTH="100%"><tr>
<td ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="30%"><tt><b>
<A HREF="http://foo.bar">Text text text...</A><BR><BR>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is the situation always the same? `<a>` tags between comments?

Comment: I might be able to tell if you post a snippet, but my guess is simple-html-dom won't be able to do it. Dom on the other hand probably can.

Comment: I added a snippet.  Relentless, yes the situation will always be the same. Nothing changes except the actual links themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but it might be better to consider the order of the tags instead of their nesting.

```
$articles = array(array());
foreach($html->find('comment, a') as $a) {
    if ($a->nodetype == HDOM_TYPE_COMMENT) {
        $articles[] = array();
    } else {
        $articles[count($articles) - 1][] = array($a->href,$a->innertext);
    }
}
```

This (rather crude) code will create an array of arrays, one for any `<a>`s before the first comment and one for each comment, each array containing zero or more articles depending on how many links appear between its comment and the next.

By the way, this code will not work on your provided code snippet, as the comments in there start with `<!` and end with `>`, instead of `<!--` and `-->`, respectively. I'm assuming the comments appear correctly in the actual HTML markup.

EDIT: Ok, the "comments" are found as they are in the snippet. In this case, it appears that  simplehtml calls all other tags that start with `<!`: "unknown". So if you add that to the code above, you have your arrays of links:

```
$articles = array(array());
foreach($html->find('comment, unknown, a') as $a) {
    if (in_array($a->nodetype, array(HDOM_TYPE_COMMENT, HDOM_TYPE_UNKNOWN))) {
        $articles[] = array();
    } else {
        $articles[count($articles) - 1][] = array($a->href,$a->innertext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Spiny Norman, Thanks. I'm going to fool with that for a bit.  Unfortunately I copied that snippet directly from the HTML and that's how the comments are, well some of them. I'm thinking I'll have better luck regex'ing this.

Comment: Hi TheEditor, those were my thoughts as well. However, I just had a look at the library and apparently there is an "unknown" tag type as well, that catches anything else that starts with `<!`. Give it a try, maybe you'll have to `array_filter()` the results but I'm pretty sure it works.